# Angular: How to implement foreach in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want implement test case for `foreach` for following code. My test case is doesn't effect any line of code in `checkAddressList()`. Please let me know if I missed anything?

app.ts

```
  checkAddressList() {
    const element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pac-container'));
    element.forEach((addressContainer: HTMLElement) => {
      addressContainer.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
```

app.spec.ts

```
  const element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.pac-container'));

  it('should display none in addressContainer', () => {
    element.forEach((addressContainer: HTMLElement) => {
      expect(addressContainer.style.display).toBe('none');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `checkAddressList` in your test.

As I see `checkAddressList` is never called

Comment: I have updated `component.checkAddressList()` in test case but still same

Comment: code after `forEach` doesnt detect as well. What I have missed ?